# How can I create an AWS UserPool client with dynamic scopes?

Tags: powershell, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I have a PowerShell script where I am trying to create an AWS UserPool App Client. I'm querying the scopes from the resource server in order specify those scopes to create the app client. I tried concatenating a string but that didn't work. I also tried adding them to an array but then I'd have to specify each indexed item individually. I could just add the first one and then step through the array to add the rest and update the app client. That seems clunky. Is there a way to lay the scopes in all at once?

```
param($pool, $name)

$id = $(aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --query "UserPools[?Name==``$pool``].Id" --max-results 20 | ConvertFrom-Json)

$resourceServer = $(aws cognito-idp list-resource-servers --user-pool-id $id --max-results 1 --query 'ResourceServers[].{identifier: Identifier, scopes: Scopes[*].ScopeName}'| ConvertFrom-Json)

$scopes = @()
# $scopes = ""

foreach ($scope in $resourceServer.scopes) {
    # $scopes += """" + $resourceServer.identifier + "/" + $scope + """" + " "
    $scopes += $resourceServer.identifier + "/" + $scope
}

Write-Host $scopes

# aws cognito-idp create-user-pool-client --user-pool-id $id --client-name $name --generate-secret --explicit-auth-flows ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH --allowed-o-auth-flows client_credentials --supported-identity-providers COGNITO --allowed-o-auth-flows-user-pool-client --allowed-o-auth-scopes $scopes

aws cognito-idp create-user-pool-client --user-pool-id $id --client-name $name --generate-secret --explicit-auth-flows ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH --allowed-o-auth-flows client_credentials --supported-identity-providers COGNITO --allowed-o-auth-flows-user-pool-client --allowed-o-auth-scopes $scopes[0]
```